# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '1399/06/31' for column 'date' in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, datetime

There is a problem with inserting `1399/06/31` into `SQL` using laravel, actually, if the day of the month is another number less than `31` there is not any problem.

**note:-**
I use the Persian calendar, not the Gregorian calendar.

```
 public function create(Request $request)
 {
     $transferMoney = new TransferMoney();
     $transferMoney->sender_id = Input::get('sender_account_id');
     $transferMoney->receiver_id = Input::get('receiver_account_id');
     $transferMoney->payment_amount = Input::get('payment_amount');
     $transferMoney->rate = Input::get('rate');
     $transferMoney->date = Input::get('pr_date');
     $transferMoney->description = Input::get('transfer_description');

     $transferMoney->save();
 }
```

Comment: june has 30 days

Comment: **June 31** is not a correct date

Comment: I am usnig persain date

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't save any format other than the conventional Gregorian calendar date into the SQL table. What you can do instead is save as Gregorian date and when retrieving, use an accessor to retrieve as Persian date all the time directly.

```
$transferMoney->date = Carbon::parse(Input::get('pr_date'))->locale('UTC+6');
```

I found a package for converting Persian time, I don't know if you need it or not. https://github.com/morilog/jalali

You can use this or your desired format in TransferMoney.php after importing :

```
public function getYourDateFieldAttribute($value)
{
    return Jalalian::fromDateTime($value);
}
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for your problem is that to change the types of your `date` from `date` to `varchar` in the SQL database because the Shamsi `date` is the unknown `date` in SQL and SQL can not support this type. like bellow:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $transferMoney = new TransferMoney();
    $transferMoney->sender_id = Input::get('sender_account_id');
    $transferMoney->receiver_id = Input::get('receiver_account_id');
    $transferMoney->payment_amount = Input::get('payment_amount');
    $transferMoney->rate = Input::get('rate');
    $date = explode('/', Input::get('pr_date'));
    // if you are using the persianDatepicker you have to also check this condition
    if($date[1] <= 9 ) {
       $date[1] = '0'.$date[1];
    } else {
       $date[1] = $date[1];
    }
    if($date[2] <= 9) {
       $date[2] = '0'.$date[2];
    } else {
       $date[2] = $date[2];
    }
    $transferMoney->date = $date[0].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[2];
    $transferMoney->description = Input::get('transfer_description');

    $transferMoney->save();
}
```